# Logic App Designer Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-logic-apps

After update to Azure SDK 3.0, Logic App Designer produces an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This happens even on a new project if I right click LogicApp.json and choose, Open With Logic App Designer.

I've uninstalled all Azure extensions and reinstalled with no luck.

When I look through the Activity Log and I find these:

```
<entry>
<record>657</record>
<time>2017/03/09 20:36:24.976</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.ActivityLogWriter</source>
<description>EditorPane.IPersistFileFormat.Load: Unexpected error occurred., Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,    at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.Utilities.ArmToolsMruPopulator.get_MruSource()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.Utilities.ArmToolsMruPopulator.AddMenuEntry(String userAccountId, String subscriptionId, String resourceGroupName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.LoadFlowResourceFromResourceTemplate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass52_0.&lt;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError[T](String operationName, String message, Func`1 function)</description>
```

and

```
<entry>
<record>658</record>
<time>2017/03/09 20:36:24.976</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.ActivityLogWriter</source>
<description>EditorPane.IPersistFileFormat.Load: Unexpected error occurred., Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,    at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.Utilities.ArmToolsMruPopulator.get_MruSource()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.Utilities.ArmToolsMruPopulator.AddMenuEntry(String userAccountId, String subscriptionId, String resourceGroupName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.LoadFlowResourceFromResourceTemplate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass52_0.&lt;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError[T](String operationName, String message, Func`1 function)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError[T](String operationName, Func`1 function)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load(String pszFilename, UInt32 grfMode, Int32 fReadOnly)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass75_0.&lt;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPersistDocData.LoadDocData&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError[T](String operationName, String message, Func`1 function)</description>
```

and

```
<entry>
<record>666</record>
<time>2017/03/09 20:36:29.591</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.ActivityLogWriter</source>
<description>EditorPane.IPersistFileFormat.Load: Unexpected error occurred., Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,    at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.Utilities.ArmToolsMruPopulator.get_MruSource()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.Utilities.ArmToolsMruPopulator.AddMenuEntry(String userAccountId, String subscriptionId, String resourceGroupName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.LoadFlowResourceFromResourceTemplate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass52_0.&lt;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError[T](String operationName, String message, Func`1 function)</description>
```

and

```
  <entry>
<record>667</record>
<time>2017/03/09 20:36:29.591</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.ActivityLogWriter</source>
<description>EditorPane.IPersistFileFormat.Load: Unexpected error occurred., Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,    at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.Utilities.ArmToolsMruPopulator.get_MruSource()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.Utilities.ArmToolsMruPopulator.AddMenuEntry(String userAccountId, String subscriptionId, String resourceGroupName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.LoadFlowResourceFromResourceTemplate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass52_0.&lt;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError[T](String operationName, String message, Func`1 function)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError[T](String operationName, Func`1 function)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load(String pszFilename, UInt32 grfMode, Int32 fReadOnly)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.EditorPane.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass75_0.&lt;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPersistDocData.LoadDocData&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError[T](String operationName, String message, Func`1 function)</description>
```

and

```
  <entry>
<record>668</record>
<time>2017/03/09 20:36:29.591</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.ActivityLogWriter</source>
<description>VsPackageMenuProvider.MenuCommandBeforeQueryStatus: Unexpected error occurred., Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsShellUtilities.OpenDocumentWithSpecificEditor(IServiceProvider provider, String fullPath, Guid editorType, Guid logicalView, IVsUIHierarchy&amp; hierarchy, UInt32&amp; itemID, IVsWindowFrame&amp; windowFrame)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsShellUtilities.OpenDocumentWithSpecificEditor(IServiceProvider provider, String fullPath, Guid editorType, Guid logicalView)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSEditor.VsPackageMenuProvider.&lt;MenuCommandCallback&gt;b__7_0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Azure.LogicApp.VSCommon.Logging.Logger.LogUnhandledExceptionAsError(String operationName, String message, Action action)</description>
```

How do I resolve this?